# Data sync between 2 microservices

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I have 2 microservices which each has its own db, the question is how 2 sync data between those 2 services, currently I have a cron job in service one which sends all the ids it has and get from service 2 all the records which service 1 does not have, but data becoming bigger and I don't think this is a good approach and what about if record got updated how to know about it? this is postgres dbs reside on cloud.

Thanks,

Comment: You seem to be attempting to implement master-master database replication.

Comment: It's like I have a microservice and I replicate the data of it into another microservice

Comment: What do you expect to gain with that? I do not want to be dogmatic but only one microservice should be the master of a certain domain. If the other service needs a read-only view on that data you may expose a REST-API in the master-service to allow the consuming service to query the data. The API could accept a "modified-since" parameter which allows the consumer to request only entities which have been created or updated since the previous call.

Comment: Service 2 is created to replicate the data in service one since service1 serve FE apps so I created service 2 which faces high traffic from other clients/developers